# Selenium (Edge) Cannot set file for upload

Tags: java, selenium, testing, file-upload, microsoft-edge

after a long research... I realized that Microsoft guys :)) not supporting `sendKeys(...)` on file input (Selenium Java running on MS Edge).

So don't think I can test file uploading on Edge...

Have anyone any Idea for workaround or something. Since manipulation on file-input element with JS is forbidden for security reasons - I just don't have more opinions in my brain.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like following:

1. define async function / method that will send keys and hit enter once file selector window appears;
2. start method #1
3. click on input type=file;
   this will most likely block further execution (depends on language)
4. wait for method #1 to complete

the most complex here is method #1. It may not work on some browsers / platforms.

Sadly - edge sucks and microsoft doesn't want to fix most edge defects.

Comment: so, as far as it won't work for all browsers/platforms - you should do it only for Edge!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the robot object.  http://www.guru99.com/using-robot-api-selenium.html

Also maybe try using "switch to".  http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/switch-commands/

I think also the actions object may work.  http://www.guru99.com/keyboard-mouse-events-files-webdriver.html